# macro or event when excel gets focus

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a macro or event I can trigger off when Excel gets focus from another application?

My Excel workbook interacts with another application via COM.  The user selects an item in a tree control in the other application and when they return to the Excel workbook, I want to update some controls with the values of the items selected in the other application.

I can get the data OK (and I do it on startup of the Workbook via Auto_Open) and populate the Excel controls.  My problem is that I can't figure out the macro or event that gets triggered when the Excel Application gets focus back.  (If there is one)

TIA,
Paolo

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing may be the best way to go.

This post on the [Mr Excel Forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=177197) may give you the information you need to get it working (see post number 6 by Jaafar Tribak).

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Alistair Collins, linking to the Mr Excel forum, only works for 32 bit Excel. As this question still gets some traffic, I thought I would post an alternative solution that also works for 64 bit Excel.

To answer the original question, the following code creates an 'event handler' for whenever the Workbook (that the code is within) window is activated. This is different to the built-in Workbook_Activate event in that it triggers **any time** the window is activated (even if it was only an Excel MsgBox or other dialog that was previously in front of it). In addition (as it may be of use to other readers), the code also creates an 'event handler' for whenever the Workbook window is deactivated.

**This code comes with a caution though.** It uses the Windows API to insert a 'hook' into the message loop to listen to window events. During development, if the 'hook' is active and a window event is passed into this code, it will crash Excel if, for example, you are blocking VBA code from running (eg if you are stepping through code with F8) or if you are editing the code that handles the windows events. So:

1. Save / backup frequently and often!
2. If you are testing the 'hook', remember to 'unhook' (i.e. manually run `UnHook` ... in the code below) before editing your code.
3. Be careful showing MsgBox's or other dialogs in the `WorkbookActivated` or `WorkbookDeactivated` procedures as you can end up in an infinite loop.

First, add the procedures that will be called when the Workbook is activated and deactivated. Here, these procedures just send a line to the Immediate window ... note the warning above about not showing MsgBox's / dialogs. In my code, I've added these to a standard Module named 'Utils':

```
' a window 'event' occurred with this workbook now being active
Sub WorkbookActivated()
    Debug.Print Time, "Workbook activated"
End Sub


' a window 'event' occurred with this workbook now being inactive
Sub WorkbookDeactivated()
    Debug.Print Time, "Workbook deactivated"
End Sub
```

Next add the 'hook' code ... the best way to learn more about the Windows API functions and constants used here is on the [MS CBTProc callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v=vs.85)) page but, in summary:

- `SetHook` tells the Windows OS that we want to be informed when a 'window event' (for example, a window is activated, gets focus, is created, is destroyed etc) takes place
- `UnHook` tells the Windows OS that we want to stop being informed of those events
- `LogWhetherHooked` is a small convenience procedure that you, as a developer, can run to test whether a hook is currently present or not
- `Callback` is the procedure that is called by the Windows OS when a 'window event' occurs ... I've added comments to this procedure to explain what it is doing, however, it essentially calls the `WorkbookActivated` and `WorkbookDeactivated` procedures (that were added to the 'Utils' Module) whenever the window for this Workbook is activated or deactivated.

Add this code to a standard Module named 'Hook':

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

' see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v=vs.85)

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "Kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
            (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal hhk As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr

    Private mlHookID As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
            (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long,ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal hHook As Long, ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

    Private mlHookID As Long
#End If


Const WH_CBT As Long = 5

Private Enum HCBT
    HCBT_MOVESIZE = 0
    HCBT_MINMAX = 1
    HCBT_QS = 2
    HCBT_CREATEWND = 3
    HCBT_DESTROYWND = 4
    HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5
    HCBT_CLICKSKIPPED = 6
    HCBT_KEYSKIPPED = 7
    HCBT_SYSCOMMAND = 8
    HCBT_SETFOCUS = 9
End Enum

Dim bIsWkbActive As Boolean

' ******************************************************************************************************************
' * Do not step through code in this Module (eg using F8) and ensure to always manually call Unhook before editing *
' * code in this Module or in other Modules called by code in this Module ... very high chance of crashing Excel   *
' ******************************************************************************************************************


' Set a 'window hook'
Sub SetHook()
    If mlHookID = 0 Then
        mlHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, AddressOf Callback, 0, GetCurrentThreadId)
        bIsWkbActive = ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).HWnd = GetForegroundWindow()
        Debug.Print Time, "Hooked (Excel window is " & IIf(bIsWkbActive, vbNullString, "not ") & "active)"
    End If
End Sub


' Remove a previously-set 'window hook'
Sub UnHook()
    If mlHookID <> 0 Then
        UnhookWindowsHookEx mlHookID
        mlHookID = 0
        Debug.Print Time, "Unhooked"
    End If
End Sub


' Is the hook currently set?
Function IsHooked() As Boolean
    IsHooked = mlHookID <> 0
End Function


' Log whether a hook is currently set
Sub LogWhetherHooked()
    Debug.Print Time, IIf(mlHookID = 0, "Is not hooked", "Is hooked")
End Sub


' The hook callback ... called every time a window 'event' takes place on the device ... see documentation at the
' above link for more details
#If VBA7 Then
Private Function Callback(ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
Private Function Callback(ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#End If
    ' we must handle all errors in here otherwise we could crash Excel
    On Error GoTo errExit

    If nCode >= 0 Then ' as required ... see documentation at the above link
        If nCode = HCBT.HCBT_ACTIVATE Then ' a window has been activated
            If wParam = ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).HWnd Then ' it is this workbook's window
                Utils.WorkbookActivated
                bIsWkbActive = True
            ElseIf bIsWkbActive Then
                Utils.WorkbookDeactivated
                bIsWkbActive = False
            End If
        End If
    End If

errExit:
    ' ensure any other hooks (eg put in place by other apps) are called correctly
    Callback = CallNextHookEx(mlHookID, nCode, wParam, lParam)
End Function
```

Once your testing of this code is completed, the various `Debug.Print` statements can, optionally, be deleted.

If appropriate for your needs, your code can just call `Hook.SetHook` and `Hook.Unhook` when monitoring of the Workbook window should start and stop. However, **it is essential** that `Hook.Unhook` is called when the Workbook is closing (otherwise you can find Excel crashing or re-starting as the hook will still be present). As such, you should add the following to the ThisWorkbook Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Hook.IsHooked Then
        Utils.WorkbookDeactivated
    End If
    Hook.UnHook
End Sub
```

The final step, only if you want monitoring to start as soon as the Workbook is opened, is to add the 'hook' from the `Workbook_Open` event. However, during development (i.e. on your own device), you may not want the 'hook' to be added automatically (but you want the hook to be added automatically on end-user devices) ... so add (for example in the 'Utils' Module you added previously)

```
' are we running code on the development device?
Function IsDevDevice() As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsDevDevice = StrComp(Environ$("username"), "XXXXX", vbTextCompare) = 0
End Function
```

... changing "XXXXX" to your username ... or you might need to adjust the return value from this Function for your needs.

Then in the ThisWorkbook Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Not Utils.IsDevDevice Then
        Hook.SetHook
        Utils.WorkbookActivated
    End If
End Sub
```

If you just want the hook to always be added (including on your device) when the Workbook opens then remove the 'If' from `Workbook_Open` and ensure `Hook.SetHook` and `Utils.WorkbookActivated` are always called.

To manually add the hook for testing during development, run the `Hook.SetHook` procedure ... but note the cautions above ... and to manually remove the hook run the `Hook.UnHook` procedure.

**Known issues**

1. If `Application.EnableEvents` is False when the Workbook is closed then `Workbook_BeforeClose` will not be called. If the 'hook' is active at that point then the problems noted above (Excel crashing or re-starting) can occur. Naturally, good code ensures that `Application.EnableEvents` is never False when it completes execution!!
2. If `Application.EnableEvents` is False when the Workbook is opened (or the shift key held down) then `Workbook_Open` will not be called and so the 'hook' will not be added. Same comment about 'good code'.
3. If the user makes changes to the Workbook and, without first saving, selects to close the Workbook but then cancels the 'Want to save your changes?' dialog then the Workbook will remain open but `Workbook_BeforeClose` will already have been called and the hook will have been removed (this, unfortunately, is just how `Workbook_BeforeClose` works and there is no `Workbook_AfterClose`, or similar, in Excel). Optionally, other event handler code can be added to re-add the 'hook' (but it is possible that Excel has been activated and deactivated, perhaps several times, in the meantime ... and it is possible that Excel is now in a different 'state' of activation/deactivation), for example in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Hook.IsHooked Then
        If Not Utils.IsDevDevice Then
            Hook.SetHook
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```